# Activating plugins wordpress when creating new theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have been creating a new Wordpress theme, I have most of everything working fine, except when I install and enable a plugin, nothing happens.

Specifically the yoast seo plugin.

Comment: Yes the submenus for yoast shows up, I have complete control over the plugin, but when I check the source code of the site which is where the plugin shows nothing is there. I have used yoast on several several themes. yoast allows the title/meta/keywords to be added for site/pages.

Comment: Did you forget to place `wp_head();` and `wp_footer();` respectively in the header and footer of the template?

Comment: That worked, something so small and over looked it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to place the Wordpress PHP functions `wp_head();` and `wp_footer();` respectively in the header and footer of the template.

Plugin scripts and stylesheets (and other important functions) are loaded through these hooks, and it is very important to always do this when creating your own template.